# R: Concatenate dataframe colnames automatically to a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, concatenation

In R: Is there an automated way to get the colnames of a dataframe (for example: mtcars):

---

`colnames(mtcars)`

output: [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

---

to a concatenated vector like this:

---

c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")

Comment: ok. so not a vector but in this form: c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colnames(mtcars)` is already a vector. The format that you have shown can be achieved with `dput` i.e

```
dput(colnames(mtcars))

c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
```